# looping within a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm stuck on the last part of this coding and need help.

Here is my task

The part I need help with is the for/if statements on comparing just the age and returning the lowest value. I know that I want to loop through all the ages and only return the lowest using if > than or < than signs but don't know how to word it in coding.

Comment: what have you tried so far? even if it doesn't work as expected, you should add it your question

Comment: edited into comments what I have so far

Answer (score 1):

Something like this seems to do the trick.

```
def youngest_at_inauguration(db):
    youngest = min((db[p][2] for p in db))
    return youngest, [key for key in db if db[key][2] == youngest]
```

You could do it by stepping through the dictionary and saving the key value if it is the minimum seen so far as well which may be more explicit if you intend for others to read your code later. This method is more of a test of Pythonic ways to do complex tasks in minimal space.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `key` argument of the [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) function to tell it what it should use when comparing elements.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through the keys  and values of a dictionary, you use `.items()`

```
for president, data in p_db.items():
    ...
```

You can even automatically expand the value tuple like this:

```
for president, (year, term, age, state, party) in p_db.items():
    ...
```

You only need to store two values, the minimum age, and a list of all presidents with the same minimum age.  You can do this with a single iteration through `p_db`

```
def func(p_db):
    min_age = None
    presidents = []

    for president, (year, term, age, state, party) in p_db.items():
        if min_age is None or age < min_age:
            min_age = age
            presidents = [president]
        elif age == min_age:
            presidents.append(president)

    presidents.sort()
    return (min_age, presidents)
```

Comment: Just do `presidents.sort()` before the return statement.

Comment: could you please tell me what switches when you want the max age?

Comment: You should be able to figure it out

Comment: i switched min_ages to max_age and switched the age<min_age to max_age<age. But still get all fails on my tests any fix?

Answer (score -1):

```
def youngestprez():
    sample_p_db =   {
    "Ronald Reagan":    (1981,  8,  69,"California","Republican"),
    "George Bush": (1989,   4,  64,"Texas","Republican"),
    "Bill   Clinton":   (1993,  8,  46,"Arkansas","Democrat")    }
    min_age = 100
    for prez in sample_p_db:
        if min_age > sample_p_db[prez][2]:
            min_age = sample_p_db[prez][2]
            prez_name = prez

    return(prez_name, min_age)


youngestprez()
```